# Use a variable as an HTML element attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jaggery-js

I am using Javascript loop to dispaly an HTML table rows. I could successfully do it.

There I use an array `replyId`

What I want is add the value of replyId[i] when running the loop to the "data-id" attribute in the following HTML tag in runtime.

```
<td id="forum_reply_content_cell_"+inputs.replyIds[i] data-id="">
```

How can I get this done?

Comment: Your attribute id value is invalid but perhaps that has something to do with "jaggery-js"? Never heard of it but you need to clear that up.

Comment: If you can append `inputs.replyIds[i]` to the ID, why can't it be inserted as the *data-id* attribute value at the same time?

Comment: With the missed <%= %> tags could solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this framework, but, from the demos I can see the you need to add `<%=` before the framework code (like .Net) and `%>` in the end. Something like this:

```
<td id="forum_reply_content_cell_<%= inputs.replyIds[i] %>" data-id="">
```

The demo source: https://github.com/wso2/product-jaggery/blob/master/apps/taskmaster/index.jag

The framework reference: http://jaggeryjs.org/

Comment: Thanks Feu. It solved my issue. That was what I wanted and has missed it.

Comment: I'm glad to hear! Good luck!